# Multivariable calculus - Limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that the function 
$f(x,y)=\frac{y}{x-y} $ for $ x\to 0 $, $ y\to 0 $ can take any limit.

Construct the sequences $ \{f(x_n, y_n\}$ with $ f(x_n, y_n)\to(0,0)$ in such way that the $ \lim_{n\to ∞} f(x_n, y_n)$ is $ 3, 2, 1, 0, -2 $.

Hint: $ y_n=kx_n $.

I am not sure if I am right, but I did the following:

$ f(x,y)=\frac{kx_n}{(x_n-kx_n)} = \frac{kx_n}{x_n(1-k)} = \frac{k}{1-k}$

$ \frac{k}{1-k}=A$

After a few steps I have obtained:

$ k=\frac{A}{(1+A)}, A≠-1$

So, the function can take any limit except -1.

Now we have:  $ A \{3, 2, 1, 0, -2\}$

If $ A=3 $:

$k=\frac{3}{4}, y_n=\frac{3}{4}x_n $

So $ \lim_{n\to ∞} \frac{\frac{3}{4}x_n}{\frac{1}{4}x_n}=3$.

For $A=2, 1, 0$ and $-2$ I did the same.

I am not sure if this is the end of the exercise. I don't understand what exactly in this context is meant by the sequence.

I also don't understand why $x_n= \frac{1}{n}\to0$ and  $y_n= \frac{k}{n}\to0$ is. How can I obtain $ x_n=\frac{1}{n}\ $ and $ y_n=\frac{k}{n}$ ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence converging to $0$ and $y_n=kx_n$ then you have

$$f(x_n,ky_n)=\dfrac{k}{1-k}.$$ (Obviously we need $x_n\ne 0$ and $k\ne 1.$ In other case, $f(x_n,ky_n)$ is not defined.) This shows that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist because for different $k$'s you get different values.

Note that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)=\lim_{(x_n,y_n)\to (0,0)} f(x_n,y_n)$$ for all sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ converging to $0$ in case the limit exists. Since the RHS has different values for different sequences you can conclude that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist.

It is not necessary to get the possible values of $\lim_{(x_n,y_n)\to (0,0)} f(x_n,y_n).$ If you have two pairs of sequences and the limit takes two different values you can conclude that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist. But you are asked for it. Indeed the question says:

> Construct the sequences $ \{f(x_n, y_n\}$ with $ f(x_n, y_n)\to(0,0)$ in such way that the $ \lim_{n\to ∞} f(x_n, y_n)$ is $ 3, 2, 1, 0, -2 $.
>   Hint: $ y_n=kx_n $.

Your construction of the sequences is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. One more question: Is it the same lim as n→∞ of (kxn)/(xn-kxn) and lim as (xn, yn)→(0,0) of (kxn)/(xn-kxn)? If n→∞, then (xn, yn)→(0,0)?

Comment: No. They are different limits. Since you are interested in $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ you need: $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n=0.$ And the other limit is $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n,y_n).$

Comment: And how is xn=1/n obtained?

Comment: You need $x_n \to 0.$ And $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1n=0.$ But you can take $x_n=1/n^2$ or other sequence converging to $0$.

Comment: So the correct answer for A=3 would be  $ \lim_{(x_n, y_n)\to(0,0)} \frac{\frac{3}{4}x_n}{\frac{1}{4}x_n}=3$ and not $ \lim_{n\to ∞} \frac{\frac{3}{4}x_n}{\frac{1}{4}x_n}=3$ ?

Comment: If I have understood correctly, $ x_n=\frac{1}{n}\ $ and $ y_n=\frac{k}{n}$ are just examples for convergence to $0$ as $n→∞$ and they are not required in the exercise?

Comment: Once you got $k=\frac{A}{1+A}$ you only need $x_n \to 0.$  $\lim_{(x_n, y_n)\to(0,0)} \frac{\frac{3}{4}x_n}{\frac{1}{4}x_n}=3$ makes no sense.